# Trouble with SP_SEND_DBMAIL using pyodbc (error on except)

Tags: pyodbc

Error is not evident - not sure how to debug the except section

```
import pyodbc
driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}'
def exec_sqlcmd(sqlcmd,cnxn):
   try:
      cursor=cnxn.cursor()
      cursor.exec(sqlcmd)
      cnxn.commit()
      cursor.close()
   except:
      print("debug in sql: " + sqlcmd)
server='tcp:server.domain.ou.ou'
database='mydb'
cnxn=pyodbc.connect(
   Trusted_Connection='Yes',
   Driver='{ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server}',
   Server='10.10.10.01,1433',
   Database='mydb'
   )
#cursor=cnxn.cursor()
profilename='serverdbmailprofilename'
recipients='me@mydomain.com'
subject='test me'
body='did you get this'
query="""Exec msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
  @profile_name=profilename,
  @recipients=recipients,
  @subject=subject,
  @body=body"""
exec_sqlcmd(query,cnxn)
cnxn.close()
```

Error is not evident - not sure how to debug the except section - works fine in ssms and sends the email.  Not a python superstar - looking for a way to debug the error in except section.

If you decide to paste and test - be sure to put the correct server name, domain name, email and so on to get a similar result.

Does the query require the three quotes?  Error is different using just one single quote.

Doesn't appear the cursor needs to be pre-declared to work.  There is an error from a script running similar queries (not this one) pointing to WinError 10060 indicating a peering issue in AWS.  The peering appears to be correct and the security groups are open correctly.   SQL server (through 1433 and subsequently pyodbc) should be working on the same port.  SQL works but not pyodbc.

Is there a different port used by pyodbc that isn't port 1433?

Comment: Lior answer the second part of this question here  (Thanks Lior) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65126577/error-exception-should-inherit-base-python-error-object

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this error condition.  In many examples, I see the short hand cursor.exec(sqlcmd)   One modification made this example work.

```
cursor.execute(sqlcmd)
```

Having said that, I am still looking for the python way to output the SQL error.