# Inherit Base Python Error Exception Object (syntax)

Tags: python, sql, vba, error-handling

In Visual Basic, there is an inherited base object that is effective for error debugging purposes.  Is there an equivalent for the "Err" object in Python?

```
Dim Msg As String  
' If an error occurs, construct an error message.  
On Error Resume Next   ' Defer error handling.  
Err.Clear  
Err.Raise(6)   ' Generate an "Overflow" error.  
' Check for error, then show message.  
If Err.Number <> 0 Then  
    Msg = "Error # " & Str(Err.Number) & " was generated by " _  
        & Err.Source & ControlChars.CrLf & Err.Description  
    MsgBox(Msg, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Error")  
End If
```

For example:

```
def exec_sproc(sql,cnxn):
   try:
      cursor=cnxn.cursor()
      cursor.execute(sql)
      cnxn.commit()
      cursor.close()
   except(err):
      print("error: {0}".format(err))
```

There is a suggestion to try

```
   except Exception,e: print str(e)
```

I get an invalid syntax because 'e' is not defined or in the former example err shows as invalid syntax.

What is the base error object in Python?  In most examples, user-defined custom errors are demonstrated rather than coding a return of the actual "Python" error.  If I know what the error is, I prefer not to make it.   Instead, show me what Python sees as the error.  (anything other than invalid syntax would help)

Comment: you can use ```expect ``` and the error name as in this case ```expect Exception:``` to by pass an error or print something when the error accrues is this what you are looking for?

Comment: as for the suggestion you are getting a error because there is nor variable/function called ```e``` just do ```print("e")``` and its going to work and there is also a typo in your ```expect``` function it should be ```expect Exception as err: print(f"there is an {err} error")```.

Comment: Your syntax error is because `except Exception,e:` is Python 2 syntax. Use `as` instead of the comma.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
def exec_sproc(sql,cnxn):
    try:
        cursor=cnxn.cursor()
        cursor.execute(sql)
        cnxn.commit()
        cursor.close()
    except Exception as err:
        print("error: {0}".format(err))
```

for more on Python exceptions look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)